# Pass image between pages

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to pass image between pages. 
On one of the pages loads a picture, so I have the source. However, I do not know how to pass this image (source) to another page?

I tried converting to a string, but I think it's not a good way to go.

EDIT:

Method 1:
First Page

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(logoQrCodeImage, null);
            if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State"))
            {
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] = wb;
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            }
```

Second Page:

```
                if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State"))
            {
                WriteableBitmap wb = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] as WriteableBitmap;
                icon.Source = wb;
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("State");
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            }
```

And error is in line:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

Error message:

> 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Method 2:
First Page:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["iconLogo"] = logoQrCodeImage.Source;
```

Second Page:

```
            Uri url = new Uri(iconImage, UriKind.Relative);
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(url);
            icon.Source = bmp;
```

Comment: image is static or coming from web?

Comment: Static - from phone library

Comment: then you can pass path too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store image as a variable in IsolatedStorageSettings, and take it out on second page.

Something like this would work.

include a method like this

```
 public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(WriteableBitmap bitmapImage)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(bitmapImage, ms,
                    bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

saving-

if Image i1 is your logo image then.

```
    WritableBitmap wb=new WritableBitmap (i1,null);
Byte [] array=ConvertToBytes(wb)
        if(!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State"))
        {
         IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] = array;
                        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }
```

Retrieval-

```
    if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State"))
            {
           Byte [] array=  IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] as Byte[];
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
                WriteableBitmap wb= new WriteableBitmap(200, 200);
                wb.LoadJpeg(stream);
    //now assign wb as a source to any image control.
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("State");
                            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            }
```

Comment: Substituted the words "Image Object" in my painting called "logoCodeImage", but the problem is in the line IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save (); \n Error message: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: How can I place WritableBitmap object of my image in place of Image Object  and take the object out as a WritableBitmap Object ?

Comment: I have an error message. I have edited my first post with my code.

Comment: ok got it, The error is purely of serialization, check new edits :).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First Page:

```
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["iconLogo"] = logoCodeImage.Source;
```

Second Page:

```
 var iconImage = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["iconLogo"].ToString();      
 Uri url = new Uri(iconImage , UriKind.Absolute);
 BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(url);
 icon.Source = bmp;
```

And you will get your Image.

Comment: I have an error: in line Uri url = new Uri(iconImage , UriKind.Absolute);                                   System.UriFormatException was unhandled by user code
 Message=Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: set the urikind as "UriKind.Relative". 
Sorry there was my mistake.

Comment: Now there is no error, but the image is not passed. (Still no source).

Comment: first you will check that there is an image string is present in that PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["iconLogo"].ToString() line or not?
Or can you update your Question now? i want to see how you were tried out this code.
Because i have implemented in my project successfully. So, Please update your question.